# regular expression to add brackets before and after a repeated text

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have the following line, and I want to add a brackets before and after it:

from:

> `<span class="Footnote">    Matt. xx. 19.</span>`

or:

> `<span class="Footnote">    1 Thess. i. 7.</span>`

and different values of verse references.. (in other words anything in between those > and <

to:

> `<span class="Footnote"> (Matt. xx. 19.)</span>`

and so on (it takes anything in between those > and < and add () before and after it..

*p.s. I use notepad++ to search and replace..*

- edit:
  the first 3 replies work great, even for anything not in the same format of the verse.. which is helpful.. however I noticed in the code some differences that doesn't get changed.. like if the code has any tags in between.. like:

  `<span class="Footnote">    [See <i>Dan</i>, note 12, p. 26, <i>infra</i>.  “Eternal” ="long.”]</span>`

or if the code is divided in more than one line!  like

> ```
> <span class="Footnote">    some text
>
> more text
>
> </span>
> ```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for

```
<span class="Footnote">\s*([^<>]*?)\s*</span>
```

and replace with

```
<span class="Footnote">(\1)</span>
```

This changes

```
<span class="Footnote">    Matt. xx. 19.  </span>
```

into

```
<span class="Footnote">(Matt. xx. 19.)</span>
```

Comment: thanks.. what if I want to remove anything that is between those > and < even if it is not on the same format?  some have text, some have letters, commas, dots..  to add () before and after anything in between?

Comment: How can you distinguish between the stuff you don't and the stuff you do want to keep?

Comment: anything between the span, /span for the class footnote.. even if it has codes or anything like <i> or whatever

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a few before/after samples?

Comment: OK: About multi-line strings: Notepad++ doesn't support multi-line regex matching. And about the tags: this is not regular any more and not matchable with regexes, least of all Notepad++'s.

Answer (score 1):

Find what:

```
Footnote">\s*([^>]+)\s*<
```

Replace with:

```
Footnote">(\1)<
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Couldnt test it, my family wants me to close the computer at Christmas breakfast).

```
  preg_replace("/Footnote">([^>]*?)</span>/i","[\1]",$subject);
```